# Does the notarization requirement for macOS Catalina require a Developer Account for local software builds?

Tags: applications, xcode, catalina

In January 2020 (date may have changed; correct me if I am wrong), notarization requirements will activate for Mojave and Catalina. This will affect every application not released on the App Store.

My question is whether this will apply to local builds created on local machines. If I want to test an app I have made on my local computer (say, with Xcode or Unity), will I need to pay for a developer account, notarize my application, and wait a few hours for Apple to reply in order to perform my testing? My current understanding is that once Apple flips the switch requiring notarization, I will no longer be able to test my own applications without Apple notarizing every single build, so knowing how things will work out in advance will be greatly appreciated.